# AngularJS and Hierarchical data with calculated fields

Tags: angularjs, hierarchy

I have an Angular page that will display a complex hierarchy of data, 4 levels deep. I want to add things like calculated totals and (fairly complex) validation at levels 2 and 3 of the hierarchy.

The data is returned via a JSON webservice, and as far as I can see I have two options:

1. Create a parallel model with my calculation/validation functions on it and map the data from the service onto that, resulting in a lot of duplication
2. Traverse over the data hierarchy returned from the service and monkey patch the calculation/validation functions

Am I holding it wrong and there a third way? Is one of the options better than the others?

A simplified contrived example, organising distribution of set of products:

The model looks like this:

```
Model
  \- State[]
       \-Regions[]
           \-Stores[]
               \-Products[] (user enters # of products per store)
```

We want to calculate/validate things like

- Total number of each product in a region
- No more the X number of a products in a region
- Fair distribution of products across region
- Total number of a product does not exceed stock

So the totalling and validation happens at the Region and Store level.

Comment: Can you give an example of your data structure, or some more context on the app? Would hope to give a better answer.

Comment: Would nested controllers for the lower hierarchies help?